# $X_n$ converges in mean square to $X$, $Y_n$ converges in mean square to $Y$ Proof $X_n\pm Y_n$ converges in mean square to $X\pm Y$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

$X_n$ converges in mean square to $X$

$Y_n$ converges in mean square to $Y$

Proof

$X_n\pm Y_n$ converges in mean square to $X\pm Y$

I try it

$E(((X_n \pm Y_n)-(X \pm Y))^2)$

=  $E(((X_n -X) \pm (Y_n -Y))^2)$

= $E((X_n -X)^2 + (Y_n -Y)^2 \pm 2(X_n -X)(Y_n -Y))$

= $E((X_n -X)^2) + E((Y_n -Y)^2) \pm  2 E((X_n -X)(Y_n -Y))$

I know

$E((X_n -X)(Y_n -Y)) \leq \sqrt{E((X_n -X)^2)E((Y_n -Y)^2)}$ (Cauchy-Schwarz inequality)

Then

$E((X_n -X)^2) + E((Y_n -Y)^2) +  2 E((X_n -X)(Y_n -Y))\leq E((X_n -X)^2) + E((Y_n -Y)^2) +2  \sqrt{E((X_n -X)^2)E((Y_n -Y)^2)}\rightarrow0$

But

$E((X_n -X)^2) + E((Y_n -Y)^2) -  2 E((X_n -X)(Y_n -Y))$ I have problem to proof that converges to 0 (Probably it is some trivial and stupid but I can see it). I need some help.

Answer (score 1):

In Cauchy Schwarz inequlaity: $EYZ \leq EY^{2}EZ^{2})^{1/2}$ you can certainly change $Y$ to $-Y$ to get $-EYZ \leq (EY^{2}EZ^{2})^{1/2}$. Apply this with $Y=X_n -X,Z=Y_n-Y$.

Comment: You are right.  For a moment, I saw the inequality, and I was multiplying it by -1 (Terrible). Thank you